Not Cyclic Module Record in ECMAScript
The ECMAScript specification has a section about the modules. Link() is a method on Cyclic Module Record that runs another method called InnerModuleLinking, which passes the current module (namely Cyclic Module Record) to InnerModuleLinking.
In InnerModuleLinking, the first step in this algorithm is this:
1. If module is not a Cyclic Module Record, then
   a. Perform ? module.Link().
   b. Return index.

What is this case where something other than Cyclic Module Record is passed?

Answer was found in JSON modules proposal.
Example of not Cyclic Module Record is Synthetic Module Record for json and css files.
So we can find here concrete method Link(), that will invoked in InnerModuleLinking algorithm belonging to the Cyclic Module Record:
1. If module is not a Cyclic Module Record, then
   a. Perform ? module.Link(). /// https://tc39.es/proposal-json-modules/#sec-smr-Link
   b. Return index.

